# Anyone can teach me IBAction how to use "isEqualToString" to a NSArray object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Anyone can teach me IBAction how to use `isEqualToString` to an `NSArray` object?

I have create an `IBAction` to play a sound whenever user touch the button.

My first page is TableView and Array a list of sound data.

"DetailModal" is an `NSArray` object from other ViewController.

I'm using AudioToolbox and I have created the sound file to soundID

How can I use `isEqualToString` to link the `NSArray` object?

For example:

I have created a list of soundID like this:

```
NSURL *buttonURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"A" ofType:@"m4a"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL1, &soundID1);

NSURL *buttonURL2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"I" ofType:@"m4a"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL2, &soundID2);
```

and

Detail2ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;
```

How can I use "isEqualToString" to a NSArray object in IBAction?

```
- (IBAction)Sound {
    int sound =  _DetailModal;

    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"/a/"]) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID1);
    }

    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"/i/"]) {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID2);
    }
}
```

I have tried but fail...

Comment: what do you want to do? touch on a sound name in listView and play it on detailView ?

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  `_DetailModal` is presumably an NSArray, and cannot be assigned to an `int`.

Comment: And if `_TitleLabel` is indeed a label, why would the text change without you already knowing what you changed it to?  Why do you need to compare it to anything?

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect candidate for NSDictionary rather than NSArray. When you build your NSDictionary you build it like this:

```
[mutableDict setObject:yourNSURLA forKey:@"A"];
[mutableDict setObject:yourNSURLB forKey:@"B"];
```

Now it's super easy to play the sound:

```
- (IBAction)onClick1:(id)sender {
    NSString *title = [(UIButton *)sender currentTitle]; 
    NSURL * soundFileURL = [mutableDict objectForKey:title];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)soundFileURL, &_MySound);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_MySound);
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I would suggest that you show the full IBAction method, including the use of `sender` to retrieve the activating button instead of `_TitleLabel`

Comment: Where is my +1 for good answer :-p  I added more details thanks for keeping up the quality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things. First, assign the button a title, then read it.

My code is similar to what you want to do, so you should be able to adapt it to your needs. In the section of my code where I create the button, I give it a title and a method to execute when it is pressed.

```
 [self.wordButton setTitle:@"w" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.wordButton addTarget:self 
                        action:@selector(wordButtonPressed:)
```

Then later, I read the title and do stuff.

```
- (IBAction)wordButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSString *whichSnd = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",sender.titleLabel.text];
    id <SayButtonsDelegate> SB_delegate = _delegate;
    [SB_delegate sayButtonPressed:whichSnd];
}
```

In my case I send the titleLabel to the delegate and it decides which sound to play, based on the title e.g. w means play the word sound, snd means play the sounds in the word, alpha means say the letters in the sound. But I think you can handle it with the if statements.